# Rails 3, :from, Net::SMTPSyntaxError (502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, cloudmailin

I'm running into this error "Net::SMTPSyntaxError (502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command"

I have this code working:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
default :from => "sammy@mysite.tv"

def comment_updated(comment, user)
  @comment = comment
  @user = user
  mail(:to => user.email,
  :subject => "[JS] #{comment.job.subject_name} -               #    {comment.job.subject_name}")

  end
end
```

But the code below throws this error "Net::SMTPSyntaxError (502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command":

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
default :from => "sammy@mysite.tv"

def comment_updated(comment, user)
  @comment = comment
  @user = user
  mail(:to => user.email,
  :subject => "[JS] #{comment.job.subject_name} -               #{comment.job.subject_name}",
   :from => "jSearch 
   <comment+#{comment.job_id}@mysite.tv>") do  |format|
    format.text
    format.html
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to use the Cloudmailin service to process my incoming emails, so I would like to have a :from address when users click reply.

Any idea why this code with the extra :from wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I can remember this being an issue that I also experienced before. I think there's a bug that prevents you specifying a full from address. From appears to only accept a valid email address. `comment+#{comment.job_id}@mysite.tv` will work but for some reason `jSearch <comment+#{comment.job_id}@mysite.tv>` does not. Unfortunately I can't reproduce this now.

The error message that you're seeing is the SMTP server stating that it doesn't understand the format of your command (I'm guessing as it passed the `MAIL FROM: jSearch <comment+1@mysite.tv>`. Unfortunately my only suggestion right now is to remove the name part of the from address.